# After Magento is installed and configured, is there a way to streamline the installation and configuration of additional modules?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, ce-1.9.0.1, xmlrpc

After Magento is installed and configured, is there a way to streamline the installation and configuration of additional modules?

For example, when deploying Odoo, one can `rsync` a module to an Odoo installation, use XML-RPC to reload the module, and any database and/or configuration changes can happen automatically. The Odoo architecture makes it easy to automate this process.

I am wondering if there are similar methods for working with Magento.

For scripting the initial installation of Magento, `install.php` is perfect:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/command_line_installation_wizard

**For scripting the installation and configuration of additional modules, perhaps there is some better documentation for mage than what I have found so far?**

https://www.yireo.com/blog/1294-magento-15-mage-command-line

Having seen how well the XML-RPC interface works for Odoo, I had hoped there might be similar functionality exposed by Magento to allow for remote automation and control of a Magento installation.

But if mage is the official tool... a link to some documentation would be amazing!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're expecting here, maybe you can clarify further? The mage script that comes with the installation is meant exactly for easy maintenance and updating. Configuration happens in the admin interface [edited for clearness and readability].

Comment: Question has been edited for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's unclear what your end goal/requirements are I would suggest you do some research on [Continuous Integration/Deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery). Here's another [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-continuous-deployment/). Using a SOAP API to deploy code seems counter-intuitive and not worth the effort when there are more established practices and tools in place.

Typically streamlining means automation. Magento (and most modern web applications for that matter) have many moving parts:

- Server configuration (users, groups, security, networking, monitoring, backups, etc)
- Application environment configuration (apache, PHP, shared storage)
- Database and caching services (memcache or redis)
- Code deployment

You must first create a series of steps to setup each of these in a consistent/repeatable fashion. Then you can being to automate these processes with tools such as Chef or Puppet for configuration management. For deployment Jenkins and Bamboo are good options for creating builds and deploying artifacts.

There are also a number of services trying to help automate deployments and configuration such as [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) and [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

Ultimately you must decide which aspect of your process would provide the greatest value to automate.

As for the root directory aspect of you're question I'm guessing you're referring Magento not having a `public` directory like other applications or frameworks. If you configure your server and Apache correctly then there's no risk.

Comment: For server deployments, Debian's package management system is my tool of choice, using a few custom packages served from a private repository. The application environment and database components are fairly simple for my needs. So that leaves code deployment. Question has been edited for clarity.